# How to return only lines that intersect for a certain length instead of just

Tags: postgresql, sql, intersection

Basically I have 2 line layers that intersect.

If I run:

```
SELECT objectid, object_class FROM table1 d WHERE st_intersects(d.geom, (SELECT geometry FROM table2 WHERE id = 75259) )
```

I get at least 10 rows, but that isn't helpful because it includes many lines from table1 where they only cross the table2 line once, instead of sharing part of the same geometry.

So I thought about st intersection and used:

```
SELECT objectid, object_class FROM table1 d WHERE st_intersects(d.geom, (SELECT geometry FROM table2 WHERE id = 75259) ) 
AND st_length(st_intersection(d.geom, (SELECT geometry FROM table2 WHERE id = 75259))) > 0.1
```

Problem is that I get no results returned, despite having at least 3 lines that intersect more than 1 meter. How to fix my query ?

Comment: I would check if ST_Intersection really returns you linestrings and not multipoints. It is hard to get a line perfectly on top of another if they do not share the same vertices.

Comment: Btw. this is what `ST_Overlaps` is optimized for. Use a tiny buffer on the smaller table (or check which spatial index kicks in, if both tables are of similar size, and buffer the other).

Comment: @user30184 it was actually returning tons of empty linestrings.. ?

Comment: That's the result when lines do not intersect. Test with `select ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)'),
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 1, 1 2)')));` compared with `select ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)'),
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 1, 1 0)')));` that returns a point.

Comment: Could you check the two intersect more than 1 meter, and post the intersection shape? Also, what SRID are you using?

`select objectid, object_class, st_intersection(d.geom, (select geometry from table2 where id = 75259))
from table1 d where 
st_intersects(d.geom, (select geometry from table2 where id = 75259))`
That will show more details about intersection